# How to use R interp1 similarly as MATLAB's?

Tags: r, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate linearly in R. 
Pseudocode is `u = interp1(u, linspace(1, numel(u), numel(u)-1));` in MATLAB where extrapolation returns NaN if the point is outside the domain (default, more [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#inputarg_extrapolation)).

- `approx rule=1` is equivalent to MATLAB pseudocode

I am not sure about the second `interp1` parameter what is not required in MATLAB so I just let unsuccessufully `y <- x` such that

```
interp1(x, y, xi, method = "linear")
```

Minimal code example (real one has > 500 k points so linear will work) and its output at the top

```
List of 2
 $ : num [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ : num [1:2] 1 2
 num [1:2] 0 1
Error in interp1(x, y, xi, method = "linear") : 
  Points 'xi' outside of range of argument 'x'.
Execution halted

library("pracma") # http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/pracma/html/interp1.html

files <- vector("list", 2)
files[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)
files[[2]] <- c(1,2)
str(files)

# Wanted, MATLAB:  u = interp1(u, linspace(1, numel(u), numel(u)-1));

xi <- seq(0,1, len = length(files[[1]]) - 1)
x <- files[[1]]
y <- files[[1]]
str(xi)

files[[1]] <- interp1(x, y, xi, method = "linear")

str(files)
```

I know the thread [using interp1 in R for matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15896299/54964) but I do not have a matrix.

Input: `c(1,2,3)`
Expected output: [1:2] datastructure

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: have you tried `?approx`?

Comment: @baptiste Yes, I tried it first but then went back to `interp1` because it sounds most closest to MATLAB pseudocode.

Comment: how does MATLAB extrapolate? The explanation of `rule` in `?approx` explains that if you set `rule=2` you get the value at the closest data extreme, but if you want to do something fancier like extrapolating linearly from the nearest two points, you might have to do some more work ...

Comment: @BenBolker It returns NaN in the pseudocode *All other interpolation methods return NaN by default for query points outside the domain.* More here https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#inputarg_extrapolation

Comment: Well, there is an `extrapolation` argument.  If you're willing to get `NA` values then this is easy with `approx()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to get `NA` values on extrapolation, [as is the default for linear interpolation/extrapolation in interp1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#inputarg_extrapolation), then `approx()` works fine:

```
files <- list(1:3,1:2)
xi <- seq(0,1, len = length(files[[1]]) - 1)
x <- files[[1]]
y <- files[[1]]
a <- approx(x,y,xi)
```

You said you wanted just a two-element vector so presumably you just want the output y-values:

```
a$y
## [1] NA  1
```

This may seem wrong, but is the correct answer to the question you actually posed. You've used `files[[1]]` for both `x` and `y`, so `approx()` should return y=x when the input is in the range from 1 to 3, and `NA` otherwise. In this case `xi` is `[0 1]`, so the first element is out of the range of the x/y data provided ...

PS I can appreciate wanting to use `pracma` for similarity to MATLAB's syntax, but -  although `pracma` is high-quality and widely used - base R functions are even more widely used/thoroughly tested ...

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations! - - I now got the syntax by studying the outputs more precisely. It actually returns a list of 2. It is quite much different than MATLAB.